# How to focus on part of a scrollabel div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have a scroll-able div.

```
<div style="width:300px;height:150px;overflow:scroll;">
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    I WANT TO BE TOP OF THE SCROLLABLE DIV,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
</div>
```

The div will show starting with the first '`hi,`' at the top. Now this is just an example, my scroll-able divs contain a lot more content than this example.

I would like to be able to somehow put focus on a certain area of the content that is displayed in the div. So with this example, the scrollbar would already be scrolled down a bit, where '`I WANT TO BE TOP OF THE SCROLLABLE DIV`' shows at the top. How

Comment: use jquery like `$("input").focus();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with pure html using a tag..

```html
<a href="#scroll">click</a>
<div style="width:300px;height:150px;overflow:scroll;">
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    <span id="scroll">I WANT TO BE TOP OF THE SCROLLABLE DIV,</span><br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
    hi,<br />
</div>
```